# Show that $|z+w|^2$ + $|z-w|^2$ = $2|z|^2 + 2|w|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $|z+w|^2$ + $|z-w|^2$ = $2|z|^2 + 2|w|^2$.

Every time I work this problem out I have $2|z|^2$ but I can not get the other piece.

Here is what I got so far. Let $z = a+ bi$ and $w = c + di$, then

\begin{align*}
|z+w|^2 + |z-w|^2 &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2\\ 
&= 2a^2 + 2b^2\\ 
&= 2(a^2 + b^2)\\ 
&=2|z|^2.
\end{align*}

I do not know if I have the wrong approach or not.

Comment: You forgot the cross terms: $|z+w|^2 = (a+c)^2 +(b+d)^2$

Comment: This is [Parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

Answer (score 6):

$$|z+w|^2+|z-w|^2 = (z+w)(\bar{z}+\bar{w})+(z-w)(\bar{z}-\bar{w})$$

Now multiply out.

Comment: so my approach was wrong so the real identity of $|z+w|^2=(z+w)(z \bar + w \bar )$

Comment: @user146269 I used the identities $|z|^2 = z.\bar{z}$ and $\overline{z+w} = \bar{z}+\bar{w}$, which makes the proof shorter.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be using $|z + w|^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ and $|z - w|^2 = a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2$. These are both false. Instead we have

$$|z + w|^2 = |(a+bi) + (c+di)|^2 = |(a + c) + (b + d)i|^2 = (a + c)^2 + (b + d)^2$$

and a similar calculation gives $|z - w|^2 = (a-c)^2 + (b - d)^2$. If you use these, you will find that their sum is $2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) = 2|z|^2 + 2|w|^2$.

Comment: thanks that helps a lot i had the right idea but the wrong manipulation